How to implement external library in Android Studio from file
I need to implement com.mindorks:paracamera:0.2.2 in my project, its no longer available through repositories and can not be downloaded.
if I use
 dependencies {
implementation 'com.mindorks:paracamera:0.2.2'

I get the following error:

Could not find com.mindorks:paracamera:0.2.2.

I have the files
paracamera-0.2.2.aar
paracamera-0.2.2-javadoc.jar
paracamera-0.2.2-sources.jar
paracamera-0.2.2.pom
which I got from second computer that has the library in C:\Users\xxx.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.mindorks\paracamera\0.2.2\
How can I implement all files, so far I tried to copy all in libs folder and "add as library"
thanks all for helping

That library has not been updated since 2017. Are you sure that it is wise to continue using it?

@CommonsWare i now its deprecated, but it works for our needs

Firstly, copy paracamera-0.2.2.aar, paracamera-0.2.2-javadoc.jar and paracamera-0.2.2-sources.jar to the directory /your_project_name/app/libs/. Then add the following code in /your_project_name/app/build.gradle to add dependencies. Finally sync project with gradle.
android {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation(name: 'paracamera-0.2.2', ext: 'aar')
}


how is it done when the plugin in the files that can be found in the .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1 folder have have jars, manifest and res folder, thanks for helping

As far as I ever known, android resource files (extracted from aar) are usually stored in .gradle/caches/transforms-2 and transforms-3 in the process of gradle sync instead of .gradle/caches/modules-2. It's so weird that I have no idea, I'm sorry. But you can still search in the .gradle/caches directory to check if there is the aar file matching the package name you want.
